# How to detect drivers that an application depends on

Tags: windows, device-driver

Given an exe, is there any way to detect device drivers on which the exe depends? Statically if possible.

Comment: [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/).

Comment: @RobertHarvey Does this work with device drivers?

Comment: It will work with anything that is statically linked to the executable.  Run a known exe against it and find out for yourself.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Are device drivers statically linked?

Comment: That's a good question.  Software has many layers.  Try it on a known exe.

Comment: I am familiar with depends.exe. Statically it works using PE imports? However interaction with a device driver happens through Windows APIs, so presumably not amenable to this approach as in general device drivers won't be statically linked to Windows dlls. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/gettingstarted/what-is-a-driver- http://www.dependencywalker.com/help/html/dependency_types.htm

Comment: All true. Of course, you could try running dependency walker on the dependencies, and on those dependencies, and so on.

Comment: Which won't work in this case as the driver modules will not be in import tables.

Comment: Surely you can get an idea of device driver dependencies by looking at the things the EXE calls?  If the EXE doesn't interact with the driver directly, then it's not really a dependency, is it?  It's something that the OS is responsible for, not the EXE.

Comment: Not a static dependency, no. Which I think highlights the problem. It isn't possible to identify a dynamic dependency statically. Probably :)

Comment: The comments are very misleading.  No, there is no way to statically verify this.  Drivers are loaded by the OS kernel, not your program.  You'd do the thing you'd normally do when testing your app for release, you install it in a VM copy of the OS versions you are willing to support.  If you have a driver dependency then you'll quickly find out.  Keep in mind that it is unlikely.  Or that you might have used the word "driver" inappropriately.  The test is the way to always do it.

Comment: @HansPassant: Not sure what misleading comments you are referring to.  I never made the claim you could find specific device driver dependencies with this; I simply said "try it."